# Settings in Android

Tags: android, application-settings

what is the best method to save settings if i close the app? I know in iOS you can add Entrys for your App in the global Settings Menu. Is there in android anything similar? Or what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your best bet would be [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Which you can read more about data storage [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) which gives you a nice overview of it, and I think this accomplish exactly what you are trying to do.